# counting in MySQL with join tables

Tags: mysql

i want to count all notice that belongs to me like from my friends and the one i have created.
and its working. but the problem when i create 1 notice it just counts all the friends am connected with.
instead counting only 1.
lets say if i have 4 friends and create 1 notice. it will just count all total friends am connected with
instead showing 1 notice. it just say 4 instead 1

```
TABLE FRIENDS

ID   REQUSTED  APPROVED
1    ME        FRIEND
2    FRIEND    ME 

TABLE NOTICE

ID ACC    NOTICE
1  ME     HEY
2 FRIEND  HELLO


SELECT count(*) FROM NOTICE JOIN FRIENDS ON NOTICE.ACC IN (FRIENDS.REQUSTED, FRIENDS.APPROVED) 
WHERE 'ME' IN (FRIENDS.REQUSTED, FRIENDS.APPROVED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how many notices you've got, regardless of your amount of rows because you've got multiple friends involved, you can do this:

Instead of `count(*)` do `count(distinct NOTICE.ID)`.